# Find the owner of the View associated to my ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm in the process of implementing a `IDialogService`. This will be called from my ViewModel, which doesn't know the View.

What would be the best approach to deduce the *Owner* to give to the `ShowDialog`?

It would be great if I could avoid to register which View is bound to which ViewModel.

If it could help, I'm using Prism(v6).

Comment: How about `window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;`?

Comment: @Kirenenko I tought about that, but if(no ideal, but if) the MainWindow opens a new Window, and this windows open a Dialog, it would not be modal to the new Window?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be modal to the `MainWindow`, regardless the calling window. Then maybe you can try `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);`

Comment: @Kirenenko This may actually works(I don't see any scenario not fitting this approach). You should post an answer with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just added some other case(like if no window is active, to take the "first" non active), or if no windows at all, just return null

Comment: Also be carefull when debugging it. I remember some failures because the main active window was the debugger.